# Blade laravel variable value type?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel

Just being curious,
Suppose I make an array in a view page

```
myView.blade.php
```

**Suppose:**

```
$array = [
  1, 2, 3
];
```

in the same page, I want to loop it with "blade" foreach

**suppose:**

```
@foreach($array as $value)
<span id="{{$value}}">{{$value}}</span>
@endforeach
```

but, I get an error like this.

```
ErrorException in 1ed42d9dadecab7c54e086f573c4cbad6576e7c3.php line 63:
Trying to get property of non-object...
```

what's happened? what type of variable actually blade converts?

Any question will highly appreciated! :)

Comment: I bet the error is caused by another code. Look into `1ed42d9dadecab7c54e086f573c4cbad6576e7c3.php` compiled view at line 63.

Comment: Post your view.

Comment: and post controller relevant code

Comment: what version of laravel you are using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better if you just pass the data to your view files from controller.

But, if you still want to do that, and you are using Laravel 5.3, you can do it like this:

```
@php
    $array = [
        1, 2, 3
    ]
@endphp
```

and then loop it:

```
@foreach($array as $value)
    <span id="{{$value}}">{{$value}}</span>
@endforeach
```

Make, sure that you declare the `$array` array before the loop.

Have a look at the [Service Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#service-injection) and [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views) on Larave's documentation aswell.

Comment: what if the array like [ 'name' =>'john snow', 'age'=>22]

Comment: In that case values will be `john snow` and `22`.

Comment: how do I convert the array to an object IF I want to get the array value like this, $value->name

Comment: Simplest way to convert array to object in php is to cast it with `(object)`:
`$array = (object) [ 'name' =>'john snow', 'age'=>22] `

Comment: In this case you have to do this:

`{{ $array->name }}` and `{{ $array->age }}`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know what do you want? But recommendly, you should init your array at controller, through it to view and foreach.

In controller,

```
return view('your view path', ['array' => $array]);
```

In blade

```
@foreach($array as $value)
  <span id="{{$value}}">{{$value}}</span>
@endforeach
```

Hope it could help, thanks.